# AAVE v3 - POLYGON - TEST <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> When running a script to deposit tokens to AAVE using a fork of the polygon mainnet

Tags: solidity

I'm testing v3 AAVE contracts on a fork of the polygon mainnet using harhat locally, but when I call de supply() function I get this error:

```
Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x794a61358d6845594f94dc1db02a252b5b4814ad)
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x794a61358d6845594f94dc1db02a252b5b4814ad)
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x794a61358d6845594f94dc1db02a252b5b4814ad)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (/home/daniel/daniel/dev/chainlink/flowmi/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1802:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (/home/daniel/daniel/dev/chainlink/flowmi/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:491:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (/home/daniel/daniel/dev/chainlink/flowmi/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1522:18)
    at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/home/daniel/daniel/dev/chainlink/flowmi/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:118:18)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/home/daniel/daniel/dev/chainlink/flowmi/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

The script I'm trying to run:

```js
const { getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();

  // Mainnet pool adready given by the deployment
  // Deposit
  // Aprove to get Matic
  const AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.11");
  //const maticTokenAddress = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010"; //mainnet
  const Pool = await getPool(deployer);
  const maticTokenAddress = "0xD65d229951E94a7138F47Bd9e0Faff42A7aCe0c6"; // testnet matic address
  await approveErc20(maticTokenAddress, Pool.address, AMOUNT, deployer);
  console.log("Depositing...");
  console.log("Address provided: ", Pool.address);
  await Pool.supply(maticTokenAddress, AMOUNT, deployer, 0);
  console.log("Deposited!");
}

async function getPool(account) {
  const PoolAddressesProvider = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "IPoolAddressesProvider",
    "0xa97684ead0e402dC232d5A977953DF7ECBaB3CDb", // mainnet pool addresses provider
    //"0x5343b5bA672Ae99d627A1C87866b8E53F47Db2E6", // testnet pool addresses provider
    account
  );
  const PoolAddress = await PoolAddressesProvider.getPool();

  const Pool = await ethers.getContractAt("IPool", PoolAddress, account);
  return Pool;
}

async function approveErc20(
  erc20Address,
  spenderAddress,
  amountToSpend,
  account
) {
  const erc20Token = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "IERC20",
    erc20Address,
    account
  );
  const tx = await erc20Token.approve(spenderAddress, amountToSpend);
  await tx.wait(1);
  console.log("Approved!");
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

When I ask for which address was provided the answer is:

> Address provided:  0x794a61358D6845594F94dc1DB02A252b5b4814aD

Which happens to be a [polygon mainnet pool address](https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/v3-mainnet/polygon) according to documentation. Notice is the same address the error gives.

I'll be most thankful if someone points out my mistake

I've tried different combinations of "mainnet" and "testnet" addresses, for the maticToken, and the pool addresses provider

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the matic address, It seems I misundertood documentation, thought the fact that matic is an ERC20 compliant implied it should not need to be wrapped to deposit.

But the script only works with the address of wrapped matic on mainnet.

Maybe is a problem of the mainnet fork, don't know but I moved on.